# Bind different implementations of same Interface using ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, ninject

I use ninject to inject my dependencies in WPF project with MVVM approach.
I have created `UserControl` that showing data in Grid, and contains a button. 
On button click every record in Grid is checked by my `IChecker` implementation injected by Ninject. The problem is, I am using two instances of this `UserControl` with two instances of `ViewModel` bound into it's `DataContext`.
I want to pass diffrent implementations of my `IChecker` to diffrent instances of same type `ViewModel`. How can I achieve that with Ninject?

Comment: how are you looking to distinguish between which instance to inject?

Comment: In my parent `ViewModel` I have got two public properties of same child `ViewModel` type which are bound to `UserControl` `DataContext` dependecy property in parent `View`. These `ViewModels` need only to use diffrent implementaion of one injected Interface, the others functionalities are same

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options, as specified in Ninject [Contextual Binding documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)

### Ninject `WhenXXX`

Some out of the box Contextual Bindings available are:

```
    Bind<IWarrior>().To<Ninja>();
    Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().WhenClassHas<ClimberNeeded>();
    Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().WhenTargetHas<ClimberNeeded>();
    Bind<IWarrior>().To<SpecialNinja>().WhenMemberHas<SwimmerNeeded>();
    Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(OnLandAttack));
    Bind<IWarrior>().To<SpecialNinja>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(AmphibiousAttack));
```

Or you can provide a predicate and use custom logic wit hthe Target tinfo:

```
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().When(request => request.Target.Member.Name.StartsWith("Climbing"));
Bind<IWarrior>().To<Samurai>().When(request => request.Target.Type.Namespace.StartsWith("Samurais.Climbing"));
```

### Custom Factory

If you're logic starts getting comlex for deciding when to inject what, you may want to implement a some sort of `ICheckerFactory` which will know which `IChecker` to create based on some parameters.

Comment: In this scenario I need to add specific attributes to my `ViewModel` class, but the `ViewModel` class type Is only one, and I need only swap implementation of `IChecker` interface. Maybe if there is an option to determine which implementation use depending on property value, that I will pass in constructor parameter, but I dont have and idea how to achieve that.

Comment: @Asvv then create a `ICheckerFactory`as noted in the second option, which will be able to check the property value, and provide correct implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your support I will research this approach and mention you back